# What is that movie with the big green alien freezing littler aliens?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

About 10 or so years ago, I remember watching a movie where there was this planet inhabited by a race of aliens. The boss alien, a big green thing, would often dip the smaller aliens in liquid nitrogen or some other deep-freezing agent if they displeased him. I don't remember much more.

Comment: Can you remember any of the plot of this at all?

Comment: I think there were these amateur astronauts that were launched off into space, and ended up on this planet by accident. They had to escape, or somehow leave the planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this an animated movie or live-action/CGI?  Were there any humans involved?

Comment: No humans that I can remember. It was CG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is [Space Chimps](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0482603/) from 2008.

Zartog is the big green villain who freezes those who displease him by dipping them in Freznar and turning them into statues.

From [Alien wiki](https://extraterrestrials.fandom.com/wiki/Zartog)

> After the unmanned NASA space probe Infinity is pulled into a wormhole, it lands on a planet called Malgor, and is discovered by Zartog, a grumpy and wicked alien who likes to torture and kill animals for his amusement by dipping them in a substance called freznar, turning them into statues. From the probe, Zartog learns much about the culture of Earth and wants to live like people. After discovering how to operate the probe, Zartog uses it to enslave the population and puts them to work, building his palace to resemble a casino. Those who resist are dunked into freznar, and decorated as statues in front of Zartog's palace.

Comment: Yes!!!! This is it! I forgot about the monkeys, though. Thank you!

Comment: @AndroidWonKenobi To be honest I'd forgotten about them too, until I found the movie. Glad it was right.